# Email body not displayed after sending from iPhone via code

Tags: iphone, email

I have couple of iPhone apps that sends an email via code.
I've noticed quite a number of emails coming in from customers where everything is populated except for the body message (i always see their signature though).

I sent a test message, using the same app from my iPhone device, and i get the message (a simple "this is a test" message).

Wondering if there are any coding that needs to occur to handle different version of iOS, or perhaps different iPhone device hardwares?

Anybody noticed this before?

Comment: I've had this same exact issue with app I've developed in the past. I chalked it up to 'user error' but I'm interested to find out if there is more too it. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider the possibility that the users are accidentally pressing send on a blank email.  Perhaps to eliminate this as a possibility, guard against blank messages in code, then if it still happens you'll know it's a real issue.

Comment: I initially thought that this was the case. But out of 30 or so emails, nearly all of them have a blank body. As far as detecting an empty body, the email api invokes the default email client, which im not sure if i have access to it. Besides, an automatic signature that is appended would deem a body always to be non-empty anyways.

Answer (score 0):

set all delegates properly
and use this

```
             MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString *sub= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Black Sheep App: %@ Specials",[[BarSplArr objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"barname"]];

    NSString *message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out these specials for %@ on %@, %@ \n\n %@",[[BarSplArr objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"barname"],day,date,[[BarSplArr objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"drinkspecials"] ];

    [controller setSubject:sub];

    [controller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
```

Comment: @raidfive. Why does this not work for older iOS? What version of iOS are we talking about? This could be the culprit.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar I guess `MFMailComposeViewController` has been available since 3.0, so you probably won't have any issues these days :) I guess I was recalling back to when 2.x/3.x were common.